# Subscribe method does not work in angular

Tags: node.js, angular

product-operations.component.ts

```
  deleteProduct() {
    this.productsService.delete_product(this.deleteID).subscribe((res: any) => {
       console.log("helloooooo");
    });
  };
```

product.service.ts

```
  delete_product(id) {
    return this.http.delete("http://localhost:3000/delete_product/" + id);
  }
```

backend

```
exports.deleteProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.param("id");
  Product.deleteOne({ _id: id })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("deleted");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

**Problem:**
In the above codes, the deleteProduct function in product-operations.component.ts doesn't work properly. More precisely, it does the removal. But after doing the uninstall, subscribe doesn't run its contents. This prevents my instant update after deletion. How can I solve this?

Comment: @FoggyDay My goal is to remove the card when it is pressed. I achieve this. But the consoleLog section in subscribe is not working.

Comment: Try this:
.subscribe(
            res => console.log('HTTP response', res),
            err => console.log('HTTP Error', err),
            () => console.log('HTTP request completed.')
        );
I suspect you are getting an error because in your server code you aren't returning a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send a response back from the server.

```
exports.deleteProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.param("id");
  Product.deleteOne({ _id: id })
    .then(() => {
      res.send({}) // or res.send({id: id})
      console.log("deleted");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500)
      res.send({error: err})
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```